# MySQL - insertion multiple insertions, page stops working

Tags: php, mysql

I have made a makegroup.php site which is supposed to create a group, and put the person in the connection table between UserID and GroupID.

..but I am not sure how to go on. The logged in user is saved in session variable $usid, but how what about GroupID? How do I fetch that right after on another page? Need I make this in steps? [Including quick DB scheme.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oFks.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php. You are open to SQL injections with this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess `GrouID` is autonumeric?

So you leave db create the id for you.

Also loos like you are trying to concat the `$groupname` value

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO group (Groupname) VALUES ('".$groupname."') ";
```

But you dont want do that because that method is vulnerable to SQL Injection attack

Use parametrized values instead

[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)